# converting pojo into multiple xml service calls

Tags: java, web-services, xslt, esb

I have a java web application running on geronimo 2.1 that collects customer risk data and sends this to a third party via a soap webservice.

I now need to send my risk data to potentially 20 different third parties all with different xml services and xml in different formats.

Some how I need to get my risk data into these new formats and send the data to the third party.

I am currently looking into this at a high level trying to figure out my options.

So far I see them as below:

1. Use xslt to transform the xml I currently have into the new xml formats.
2. convert my pojo into a pojo specific to third party and then convert that pojo to XML
3. Use an ESB

I have no knowledge of XSLT or ESB other than what I have read in the last week.
Really looking for some guidence on what would be the best approach.

Also going to need to manage the 20 request that will be sent to the third parties as these will all be asynchronous.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider your third party platforms before jumping on to a solution. The reason being for example if you expose your services using REST web service which is simpler to develop and your third parties support it, then this would be a good idea. Otherwise you can use SOAP web services. I think ESB might be an over kill in your case. Yes, you can use XSLT to transform your xml in relevant format before publishing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. unfortunately I do not know what platforms the thrid parties will be running. We will be looking to add these slowly over a period of time.

Comment: If i was to use XSLT to transform to several different format wouldnt this present a problem with soap services as these are called directly from the java.

Comment: If you change xml, that would automatically change underlying mapping with Java objects so is the WSDL. But, what I was saying is to send out your transformed xml as a string within CDATA section for the client code to handle.